# UIMA Ruta Combining MATCHEDTEXT and Star or Plus Reluctant

Tags: uima, ruta

I wanna create a Match over multiple Words using MATCHEDTEXT. For selecting multiple words I wanna use the Star or Plus Reluctant quantifier. This works fine, if there is no Rule Element behind the MATCHEDTEXT part but if there is one, like the last "SW" in my example, the "CW+?" Part won't match.

**My Test String**

```
small Large Large small.
```

**My Ruta Rule**

```
STRING test;
DECLARE myObject(STRING label);
SW (CW+? { -> MATCHEDTEXT(test), CREATE(myObject, "label"=ao) }) SW;
```

Comment: Do you need to match "Large Large" from your test string right?What is ao ("label"=ao) ?

Comment: STRING test;
DECLARE myObject(STRING label);
SW CW+? { -> MATCHEDTEXT(test), CREATE(myObject, "label"=test) } SW;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in UIMA Ruta <=2.5.0. The match fails because the reluctant quantifier has some problem with the composed rule element.

You can fix your problem either by removing the composed rule element which is not required:

```
SW CW+? { -> MATCHEDTEXT(test), CREATE(myObject, "label"="x")} SW;
```

...or by avoiding the reluctant quantifier, which is also not required:

```
SW CW+ { -> MATCHEDTEXT(test), CREATE(myObject, "label"="x")} SW;
```

*DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta*

Answer (score 1):

With Plus Greedy:

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example;  
DECLARE myObject(STRING label);
STRING test;
DECLARE myObject(STRING label);
SW CW+ {-PARTOF(myObject) -> MATCHEDTEXT(test), CREATE(myObject, "label"="ao") } SW;
```

With Plus Reluctant:

```
PACKAGE uima.ruta.example; 
DECLARE myObject(STRING label);
STRING test;
DECLARE myObject(STRING label);
SW CW+? {-PARTOF(myObject) -> MATCHEDTEXT(test), CREATE(myObject, "label"="ao") } SW;
```